# Why don't JavaScript properties update automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, properties

I have an object with a property that stores the `checked` property of a checkbox like so:

```js
var x = {
  isChecked: document.querySelector("input").checked
};


function getX() {
  (x.isChecked ? console.log("checkbox is checked") : console.log("checkbox is not checked"));
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button onclick="getX()">is the checkbox checked?</button>
```

When checking and unchecking the checkbox, the `isChecked` property's value doesn't update. Why might that be?

Comment: Because `document.querySelector("input").checked` returns whether the checkbox was checked at the time it was executed.

Comment: Why do you need an extra object when you can ask the checkbox itself?

Comment: I am using an object to store and read dom properties just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.checked` is a boolean, not an object, when you say `isChecked: document.querySelector("input").checked`, you're just setting `isChecked` to the current value of `element.checked`. Make `isChecked` a function to get the actual value every time you need it.

```js
var x = {
  isChecked: () => document.querySelector("input").checked
};


function getX() {
  (x.isChecked() ? console.log("checkbox is checked") : console.log("checkbox is not checked"));
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button onclick="getX()">is the checkbox checked?</button>
```

Alternatively, if you want to continue using it with `isChecked` and not `isChecked()`, and you want to be able to set it manually with that variable, you can use getters and setters like this:

```js
var x = {
  get isChecked() {
    return document.querySelector("input").checked;
  },
  
  set isChecked(checked) {
    return document.querySelector("input").checked = checked;
  }
};


function getX() {
  (x.isChecked ? console.log("checkbox is checked") : console.log("checkbox is not checked"));
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button onclick="getX()">is the checkbox checked?</button>
<button onclick="x.isChecked = false">uncheck</button>
<button onclick="x.isChecked = true">check</button>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to briefly explain arrow functions in your answer.

Comment: There are many explanations for arrow functions out there. In this simple form, instead of saying `function() { return document.querySelector("input").checked; }`, you can just say `() =>  document.querySelector("input").checked` since they are no arguments and you want an implicit `return`